# Does Amazon AWS provide open authentication same as facebook/twitter and google

Tags: java, php, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to know that as facebook , twitter and gmail etc. provide open authentication for login in to other application.Means as we can login into other websites using facebook ,twitter and gmail etc. authentication .Does Amazon web services (AWS) provide the API for authenticating user.

If any one have used this .please assist how to allow user signup using aws account.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a Login with Amazon button on your website to allow users to log in with their Amazon credentials.In order to integrate Login with Amazon with your website or app, you must first  [sign up](http://login.amazon.com/manageApps).

A developer guide for login with amazon.

[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/lwa/dev/docs/website-developer-guide.*TTH*.pdf](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/lwa/dev/docs/website-developer-guide._TTH_.pdf)

Comment: @Viccari, I am not sure you are aware about this or not, Login with Amazon.com (retail website) and  AWS (Amazon Web Services) is no difference. Its a common user authentication system used by Amazon for its different sites. Here is a link from Amazon, that says "Help secure customer information by leveraging the same user authentication system used by Amazon.com. Login with Amazon is based on OAuth 2.0, which has been broadly adopted for user-authorized exchanges across sites."
http://login.amazon.com/
And your amazon logins are same across its sites not just two different  for retail and aws

Comment: @Viccari, so r u saying an AWS user can not login to  a system which implements "Login with Amazon" in other words can not "Login with Amazon" authenticate AWS users??